# How to use afterSubmit of jqGrid while doing Form Editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have one jqGrid where I am doing Form Editing. 
Getting options with below values.

```
$("#usergrid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#usergridpager",{add:true,edit:true,del:false,search:false,refresh:true},{},{},{}}
```

I want some error message if there is anything wrong happens while adding data into DB. I tried with

```
    // add options
    {closeAfterAdd:true, 
     closeOnEscape:true, 
     url: "adddata.html",
     recreateForm:true,
     afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) {
        return [false, response.responseText, ""];
        // Tried with return [true, response.responseText, ""]; and few more
     } 
  },{}
```

I am trying to insert existing data(primary key collision) so that I could test above method but not getting any message on display. But server console is getting proper failed log. Instead at the top of popup window I get

`"error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error code: 500"`

How to customize these messages and show them in little user friendly form.

**Update -** the value in URL attribute is mapped with one Spring MVC's Controller in my java code which is actually doing all insert/update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback `afterSubmit` will be called in case of receiving **successful** response at the end of form editing. If HTTP request to save data failed then `errorTextFormat` callback will be processed.

It's recommended additionally to use exception handles inside of server code. It allows mostly to produce more readable error as "Internal Server Error. Error code: 500". It's typically that the exception during database operations contains more information. One can catch such exceptions and return a readable error back to the client.

You should change the code of `afterSubmit` so that you distinguish successful saving from non-successful. The current code returns allways `return [false, ...]` so jqGrid will never end of editing.

Comment: Hello @Oleg. As you said afterSubmit will be called only in happy scenario and I do not want that. I need to show some message whenever there is something went wrong. I tried with "errorTextFormat" as well but its not working too. I modified my java code as well. Earlier I was not handling any exception but now I am. But even if there is any issue, my popup window is getting closed, record is not getting added (which is expected) and not getting any message too. I am returning String from my method. Anything wrong you see?

Comment: I tried like errorTextFormat : function(data){   
       return data;  }. Returning "success" or "failure" from java code but its not working.

Comment: @Jaikrat: All what I want to say is that you should manage the problem **on the server side** using the possibility which provides your server framework. If the server returns response with HTTP status code which is error then `errorTextFormat` will be called. If HTTP status code is successful then `afterSubmit` will be called and the callback can analyse the server response and inform jqGrid that the request do failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show server error in UI with proper message then we do not need to handle any kind of excpetion in our java code. Just let it come to UI. Write something like below code

```
{closeAfterAdd:true, closeOnEscape:true, url: "adddata.html",recreateForm:true,
    beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
    $('#tr_userId', form).show();
    },errorTextFormat : function(data){
      if (data.status == 500) 
          return data.responseText;  //Little HTML parsing you'll have to do
    }// add options
}
```

Comment: If you don't catch exceptions then the user will see messages like `"Internal Server Error. Error code: 500"`. If you catch exceptions on the server side you can return to jqGrid **more detailed error message**. So the user will see either "duplicate data" error or "connection to database server can't be arrived" or some other.

Comment: @Oleg, I tried returning few String based on some conditions but those were not reaching to errorTextFormat and I was not able to show anything. Here I am not really returning "data.responseTest" but some proper user friendly message.

Comment: I wrote you in other comment that you have to set **error HTTP status code** (400 and higher, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) if you want that response will be processed by `errorTextFormat`. Try `return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`,  `return new ResponseEntity<String>("some error response", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);` or other `HttpStatus`.

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to throw 500 or 404 exception from my java code. Based on this I'll show different error messages.

Comment: @Oleg,I am not seeing any difference between these two approaches. Even if I dnt throw any exception control is coming to my 'errorTextFormat' block and executing (in exception case) and if I throw exception using either 'response.sendError(500)' or the ways you suggested. Its happening the same. I know we can filter out the kind of exception in our catch block and can set different-different error code and based on that we can show different error message to the user. Is it the only reason you want me to throw exception from my java code?? Possible for you to help me!!

Comment: it's better to write comment to my answer. I wrote that 1) successful responses (with HTTP status code < 400) will be processed by `afterSubmit` and failed (with HTTP status code >= 400) will be processed by `errorTextFormat`. It's my main answer on your question. Additionally I gives **recommendation** to catch exception **to provided more detailed information about the error** on the client side. The implementation could be depend on framework which you use.

Comment: I use for example ASP.NET. If I don't catch exceptions on the server side then any exception produce **Internal Server Error. Error code: 500** without any details. If I catch exceptions some exception texts could be empty, but I can examine the exception stack and can find the first parent exception with non-empty message. Then I return HTTP response with 500 error for example, but with detailed text of the exception. Back to your case: do you see in the server response any information about primary key collision? Which error will be reported if the database server will be temporary down?

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for all your follow up comments.